# Drupal 7 Web Experience Toolkit - How to modify theme?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have been going insane trying to figure out how to modify the WET-BOEW distribution of Drupal 7 and have been met with little to no results.

http://drupalwxt.github.io/

I do not have a lot of experience with drupal.  I used it many years ago and I hated it as much then as I do now; unfortunately, employment requirements have forced me to dig into it again.

How do I go about modifying the theme? Even just modifying the header would be a massive step in the right direction.

*For the record, the files I am modifying are in `/profiles/wetkit/themes/wetkit_bootstrap/templates`*

- Modifying `system/page.tpl.php` has no effect
- Modifying `system/html.tpl.php` has an effect, unfortunately I am met with $page_top, etc and no actual markup for the header.

I am completely and utterly lost.

---

EDIT 1

I have created a folder under `/sites/all/themes` called "playground".  In this file, I have added my basic info and copied the regions from the original wetkit info file.

I created the structure for `<theme>/templates/system` and added an `html.tpl.php` file containing a die() to test if it is overriding the base theme...it does not appear to be.

I make a point of clearing the cache after every change.

---

EDIT 2 (Solution)

It turns out that I was trying to modify the wrong file all along.  For the WET-BOEW Drupal 7 distribution, changing the markup is done through `<theme>/templates/panels/page--panels--wet-boew.tpl.php` and by adding a custom CSS file to `theme_name.info`.

I'm sure this is all elementary stuff, but I've been struggling with it for a while now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, go to appearance page (url: `/admin/appearance`) and see what theme is used. Maybe you are changing wrong theme.

Then, check if page caching is on on performance page (`/admin/config/development/performance`). If so, you may need to clear the cache after every change with "Clear all caches" button on same page.

Oh and those system template files are usually overwritten with custom theme files. So don't change them.

Again, theme template files are usually placed in directory:

/sites/all/themes/theme_name/templates

starting from website root, so look for the files there or on some similar location if you have some specific site settings (multisite or something).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I go into root/sites/all/themes there is actually nothing in there.

I will update the original post to explain what I've done since reading your message.

Comment: You have to find out where your theme is located. View page source and find something characteristic for your theme. Some unique css class or element id. And then search through all your files for that term. If files are on server use grep command so you don't have to download all files (assuming it's hosted on linux server).

Comment: That was the first thing I did, actually.  I was able to find a number of files that looked like they fit the bill, but wasn't having any luck seeing my changes reflected after a cache flush etc.

What I've managed to find is going to be added to the original question.  Thanks for your help :)